# Is equality an algebraic structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A set $S$ is called an algebraic structure with respect to binary operator $*$ if it follows closure property.

$(\mathbb{N},+)$ is such example, as sum of natural numbers gives natural numbers.

Is $(\mathbb{N},=)$ also algebraic structure?

My professor said NO, but I guess it should be, as it clearly follows the closure property:

$1 = 1$ 
$2 = 2$
$...$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In brief, what is the numeric value of "$2=2$"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a sort of "type error" here: equality is a **relation**, not an **operation**. A binary operation on a domain $X$ takes in a pair of elements of $X$ and outputs *another element of $X$*, not a Boolean (true/false).

It's also worth noting that the term "algebraic structure" is not a very standard one; in general, I would expect different texts to have slightly different interpretations of the term, if they use it as a technical term rather than an informal phrase at all (I *wouldn't* for precisely this reason).

Comment: Isn't "algebraic structure" generally used for structures interpreting purely functional signatures? (Even if sometimes an order relation or something else sneaks in? :p

Comment: Yes, I guess there is only some confusion about size issues, namely if the operations need to have finite arities. In most texts this is understood, though. And one speaks of infinitary (or bounded) structures when necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Equality is a binary relation, not a binary operation. It returns a truth value for every pair of inputs, not an element of the same set. Relations and operations are fundamentally different objects, and relational structures behave quite differently from algebraic (operational) structures.

Answer (score 5):

In the expression "1=1", the equals sign is generally taken as an infix binary function with the tuple (1,1) as an input and a boolean indicating whether equality holds as output.

$\mathbb N$ is not closed under equality. For a space to be "closed" under an operator means that the output of the operator is in that space. The output of equality is a boolean, not a natural number.

The term of "operator" on a space generally refers to a function that takes a tuple of elements of that space, and gives an output that is in that space. Given that definition, equality isn't an operator on $\mathbb N$.

Your confusion may stem from thinking of the equality symbol as representing "evaluation". That is, rather than "1=1" having both sides as inputs, you're thinking of it having the left side as input, and the right side is output. So, for instance, "5+2=7" in this formulation means `eval(5+2)=7`. This is a common misperception that people likely get from elementary school, where such formulations as "2+5=" are often put on worksheets, and students learn from context that the equality symbol is being used to convey "I want you to tell me what the left side simplifies to".

There are quite a few problems with this interpretation. One, under this interpretation, equality isn't binary, it's unary, as it takes single input (one expression). Second, this would mean that equality takes an *expression*, rather than a *number*, as input. So strictly speaking, "1=1" wouldn't be taking the natural number 1 as input, it would be taking the expression "1" as input.  In Computer Science terms, `eval` generally takes a string, rather than a numeric, as input. Third, this would make equality non-symmetric. "2+5=7" would be a valid use of the equals sign, but "7=2+5" wouldn't. Fourth and most importantly, this simply isn't what the equals sign means in rigorous mathematics. It is effectively what it means in a lot of math classes, especially in elementary school, but it isn't what it "really" means.

Answer (score 3):

> Where am I going wrong?

Equality is not a operation/function, it's just a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics))

> A set $S$ is called an algebraic structure with respect to binary operator $∗$ if it follows closure property.

I suppose demanding $*$ be binary is not so nice, as it excludes, say, $\mathbb{N}$ with the unary sucessor operation. If we allow for a [more flexible notion of 'structure'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)), then well, we *could* say that bare **sets** (with no functions/operations at all, and no relations besides equality) are precisely the structures for the "theory of equality relation" :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be clear that there are three basic categories of operators:

- Arithmetic operators, which input two numbers and output a number (e.g., $+ - \times \div$).
- Relational operators, which input two numbers and output a boolean (e.g., $= < > \leq \geq \neq$).
- Logical operators, which input two booleans and output a boolean (e.g., and, or, xor).

The OP's example of "$1 = 1$" et. al. makes use of a relational operator, such that the output value is "true" (not a number), and that's not an element of the domain. In other words, $\mathbb N$ is not closed under $=$.

Answer (score 0):

An operation should be a binary function from $S\times S$ to $S$.

Meanwhile, even if $=$ is indeed a binary function. It image is unlikely the set $S$, but at most $\{ \#\text{t}, \#\text{f}\}$, where t stands for true, and f stands for false. So if your set is exactly $\{ \#\text{t}, \#\text{f}\}$, then you can call this an algebric structure.

As for the formal definition of algebric structure, I believe the following one is useful under most of the circumstances:

An algebric structure is a set $S$ together with an operation. Here an operation is a function $f\colon S\times S\to S$

And this is exactly the definition [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)).

Answer (score 0):

For the record: when viewing $=$ as something that takes two inputs in $\mathbb{N}$ then all the other answers are correct. But given the role of 'closure' in the original post, I think maybe the Original Poster views $=$ as something that takes *one* input in $\mathbb{N}$ (and produces, for each input an output in the same set), i.e. a [unary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation).

---

From that perspective the question is a) if sets with unary operations (and ternary and quaterary operations for that matter) also counts as 'algebraic structure' and b) if, when the answer to a) is yes, we still want to exclude $=$ from the class of examples of unary operations. (Note that it doesn't occur on Wikipedia)

For a) I am inclined to say yes, although as someone above points out the term 'algebraic structure' is not very common, or only used informally and not with a precise definition. Also I notice that the precise definition quoted in the original post explicitly talks about binary operations only.

For b): this comes down to personal opinion, but I'd say that a notion of equality lives on a 'higher' 'meta' level than the algebraic structure you are trying to define, basically because you already need some notion of equality in your head before you can define anything at all. Conversely, if you want to talk about a unitary operation that takes an input and then outputs that exact same element, one would normally use a name like Id instead of = and then write the definition as "Id(x) = x for all x". Note that the Id is being defined here, while the $=$ is used outside the structure, in the real world so to speak, as part of the pre-existing language that helps us make definitions. So viewing = as a unary operation is maybe technically correct, but not something anyone would do in practice I believe. But as I said, this is largely subjective.